# How to find the node with the smallest value in a given level?

Tags: recursion, tree, min

So I want to write a recursive function that returns the smallest value at a given level in a binary search tree. 
I've written this code but it only works if the bst is a full binary search tree. (every node has 2 children). 
Example : 
if my tree was :

root is equal to 3

right child is equal to 4

left child is equal to 1

And the call was the root with level 1, it returns 1. which is exactly the value I want.

but with this tree: (Same call)
root is equal 2

left child is equal to null

right child is equal to 3

it returns 0 (NULL). because 0 < 3. when I want it to actually return 3.

The code I used:

```
int minAtLevel(AVLNodePtr root, int level)
{
    // If the tree is empty
    if (root == NULL)
        return 0;

    // if level becomes 0, it means we are on
    // any node at the given level
    if (level == 0)
        return root->key;

    int x = minAtLevel(root->left, level - 1);
    int y = minAtLevel(root->right, level - 1);

    // return maximum of two
    return min(x, y);
}
Thanks.
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to return `INT_MAX` from `limits.h` than `0` or some other value that is not being used? It is guaranteed to the the highest value such that `min(theNextHighestValue, INT_MAX) ; //==> theNextHighestValue`